# Odd and confusing Xcode breakpoint

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've been working on a web service for my application in Swift, but I just tested it and it gave me a weird breakpoint at a line in `swift_dynamicCastObjectObjCClassUnconditional`.

It occurs at

```
0x104bbb7a2:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax) and says "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_l386_BPT, subcode=0x0)"
```

It occurs when I after I press my button.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, NSURLConnectionDelegate {

    lazy var data = NSMutableData()

    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    @IBAction func attemptLogin(sender: UIButton) {
        if(usernameTextField.text == "" || passwordTextField.text == "") {
            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Invalid Credentials", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            attemptConnection(usernameTextField.text, password: passwordTextField.text)
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var tapBackground: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard:")
        tapBackground.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapBackground)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func dismissKeyboard(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func attemptConnection(username: String, password: String){
        let urlPath: String = "http://notmywebsite.com/getusers.php?username=" + username + "&password=" + password
        var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!
        connection.start()
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){
        self.data.appendData(data)
    }

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
        var err: NSError
        var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
        println(jsonResult)
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }


}
```

Comment: its shows that your application crashing at that place

Comment: show me line where you get that breakpoint

Comment: Add exception break point as i show in this image and let me know which line is crashing https://www.dropbox.com/s/rq4o7vdldrsyhge/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-11%20at%2011.55.50%20am.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in line below

```
 var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
```

convert it as

```
 var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)
```

**Problem is** 
Data which is return from JSONObjectWithData can be NSArray or NSDictionary and you are forcing it to be a NSDictionary
 
**More detail**
[might be same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065536/downloading-and-parsing-json-in-swift)

---

**Edit**
Simple example of working with `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData`
[Download project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ay5mzxllydh6txo/demoRestClient.zip?dl=0)

**Code**
Fetch data using rest client

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: { (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if data.length > 0
            {
                var greeting :NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: nil) as NSDictionary;

                let id  = greeting["id"] as Int;
                let responce  = greeting["content"] as NSString

                self.lblId.text = "Id : \(id)"
                self.lblResponce.text = "Responce : \(responce)"

                myButton.setTitle("Fetch data", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

                println(greeting);
            }
        })
```

In above code if i write

```
var greeting :NSArray! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: nil) as NSArray;
```

Insted of

```
 var greeting :NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: nil) as NSDictionary;
```

Application crash with error same as you mention in your question
[image]

**Conclusion**
Error is in the line while you parsing data using JSOnSerialization
Data you get from web service is not NSDictionary for sure.
Try to print data in log and see what you get

Comment: did you read the answers given in the link ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065536/downloading-and-parsing-json-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

You should probably need to use Optional Casting. It is a type safe if you're not sure of your data returns. Also use AnyObject then verify if it is really an NSDictionary or just a nil value. Passing nil to a non-nil var or non-Optional var will crash your App.