# Swift Dynamic Cast Failed on NSJSONSerialization

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I have a [JSON Data](http://mylivecanvas.com/j3.html) which looks like:

```
[ 
{ "Name" : "Ernst Handel", "City" : "Graz", "Country" : "Austria" },
{ "Name" : "Wolski Zajazd", "City" : "Warszawa", "Country" : "Poland" }
]
```

and I am converting it to NSDictionary using:

```
var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(
 data,
 options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers,
 error: nil)
as NSDictionary
```

Comment: can you show your jsonResult dictionary?

Comment: @karthikeyan I have the link on "JSON Data". It's http://mylivecanvas.com/j3.html

Comment: make it as NSMutableArray Instead of NSDictonar nslog your result here

Comment: When I try NSMutableArray, it shows no output. I am trying on a playground.

Comment: your response data seems to be  array try my below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use this. Works for both numeric and associative types of JSON. It works for your as well. I tried.

```
func JSONParseArray(jsonString: String) -> [AnyObject] {
if let data = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
if let array = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: nil)  as? [AnyObject] {
    return array
}
}
return [AnyObject]()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON contains root object of type NSArray, not NSDictionary

```
var jsonResult: NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(
 data,
 options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers,
 error: nil)
as NSArray
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer this..it may help you

[this is my json](http://agilerise.com/hotel/Meghanabiriyani/json/productlist.php?type_sub=Veg%20Starters)

and i have  parsed like this..

Its look like same result..

```
var err: NSError
        var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
        println(jsonResult)
      self.productsArray = jsonResult.valueForKey("products") as NSMutableArray
          println( self.productsArray.count);
        var toInt: Int = self.productsArray.count
        for value in 1...toInt-1
        {
            self.valuesArray.addObject(productsArray.objectAtIndex(value).valueForKey("item_name")!)

        }
```

self.valuesArray,self.productsArray are mutable array

Comment: I am using a playground. Can't use `self`. Anyway, plus 1 for your effort. Thanks :)