# Json parsing with swift in ios

Tags: swift

I have a json like this:

```
[{"id":"1","username":"test"},{"id":"2","username":"test 2"}]
```

I need to parse them but how ? I need to do that with swift.

Comment: Before you post a question, search Stack Overflow for previous questions. This has been asked and answered many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tutorial:http://www.raywenderlich.com/82706/working-with-json-in-swift-tutorial

related question1:[How to parse a JSON file in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24013410/how-to-parse-a-json-file-in-swift?rq=1)

related question2:[Downloading and parsing json in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065536/downloading-and-parsing-json-in-swift?rq=1)