# How to Convert Json response to Swift 3.0, older conversion is throwing Error?

Tags: json, swift

This program is an HTTP connection.
How convert (**responcsestring**(variable)) to array?

```
let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://467.143.211.12/nvn/modules/pm/")
    let requset = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
    requset.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let postString = "request=data&from=now&serial=\(p)&password=\(i)&imei=testimei"
    requset.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(requset) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {

            println("eror=\(error)")

            return

        }
        println("responce = \(response)")


        let responcsestring = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        println("responce data = \(responcsestring)");
```

When I use this code:

```
          var error: NSError?
        let jsonData: NSData = data

        let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &error) as! NSDictionary
```

I am faced with this message:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFArray' (0x110870650) to
>   'NSDictionary' (0x1108708d0).

When I refer the solution, the older conversion code using in swift was not working with Swift version 2.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a JSON file in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24013410/how-to-parse-a-json-file-in-swift)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065536/downloading-and-parsing-json-in-swift

Comment: Please, it is response, not responce.

Answer (score 0):

```
var error: NSError?
let jsonData: NSData = data

let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &error) as NSDictionary
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only anwsers. Can you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: Thank
Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x100be0448) to 'NSDictionary' (0x100be08d0).
What is the message?

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with JSON, you always convert the original `NSData`. Don't try converting it to a string and converting that. It's a waste of time, space, and can introduce bugs.

The conversions are in the class `NSJSONSerialization`. Since `NSJSONSerialization` doesn't know ahead whether it parses a dictionary or an array, it returns either.

The code in the other reply tried to convert the result to an `NSDictionary` which obviously fails if you got an array. That's the message that you received. Go back to your basic Swift to look at what `as!` and `as?` do to fix this.

But seriously, if you ask for an array and someone posts an answer that tries to give you a dictionary, you should figure out yourself how to adapt that answer. Any answers here are just to get you into the right direction; it's still your responsibility and your code to write.

Comment: 1. just to be sure I understand you. You said you can convert a JSON which is wrapped into a dictionary into a `String` and then convert that using `NSJSONSerialization` to a dictionary, Array? However since you can do it directly it would be a waste of time? 2. *and can introduce bugs.* <-- like what?

Answer (score 0):

This is a asynchronous type so use it in do, catch like this . Always try to use asynchronous types when you extract information from a JSON file. Then you can enhance you app's user experience and responsiveness

```
do {
        let jsonData:AnyObject? = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
        if let list = jsonData as? NSArray // or PUT  NSDictionary ( according to your JSON )// 
        {
           // DO YOUR DATA HANDLING 
        }

   } catch let error as NSError {
        print("error")
    } catch {
        // Something else happened.
        // Insert your domain, code, etc. when constructing the error.
   }
```