# Printing json in swift after download/parse

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to get the JSON from a website and parse it before printing it.
I've got a class called "JSONImport", which should handle a JSON Import from a server and print it. 
A second class should make the call to start the Import and print the content of the JSON.

The following code is what I have so far (I took it from another question [Downloading and parsing json in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065536/downloading-and-parsing-json-in-swift/35203739#35203739))

So this is my "JSONImport.swift":

```
var data = NSMutableData();

func startConnection(){
    let urlPath: String = "http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value";
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!;
    let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url);
    let connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!;
    connection.start();
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){
    self.data.appendData(data);
}

func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
    // throwing an error on the line below (can't figure out where the error message is)
    do{
     let jsonResult: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary;
        print(jsonResult);}
    catch {
        print("Something went wrong?");
    }
}
```

Inside another class, I would like to print the JSON by:

```
JSONImport.startConnection();
```

Now I get an error, because swift wants me to add a parameter to the call, making it look like:

```
JSONImport.startConnection(<#T##JSONImport#>);
```

Does someone have an idea, what I should put in there as a parameter?
I am confused, as i didn't declare one.

Thank you all in advance!

Kind regards, Manuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startConnection()` is a instance method, so you need to instantiate an `JSONImport` to call it.

Only type methods can be used that way. So it's essentially asking for an instance of `JSONImport`.

Here is how you should do it

```
let importer = JSONImport()
importer.startConnection()
```

or by calling from the type method

```
let importer = JSONImport()
JSONImport.startConnection(importer)
```

You can read more about instance/type methods at this [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html)